# render blocked script type="text/plain" again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m blocking javascripts like this. The script is not executed.

```
<script type="text/plain" data-cookieconsent="statistics">
alert("Execute script");
</script>
```

After a click I want to execut the scripts again by changing the type to text/javascript and render it again. My approach is:

```
$('script[data-cookieconsent="statistics"]').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith(eval($(this).text()));
});
```

This works fine but not with src scripts like this

```
<script type="text/plain" data-cookieconsent="statistics" async src="https://www.example.com/myscript.js"></script>
```

How can I approach this to execute again all scripts where data-cookieconsent="statistics"?
Has anyone an idea?

Comment: I'd suggest using a dynamic script loader (eg. `$.getScript()` as you're using jQuery already) instead of changing the `type` of a `script` element at runtime. Not least because it avoids the use of `eval()` which is incredibly bad practice, but also solves the issue of the `async` remote call being ignored on a `type="text/plain"` script tag.